# Suggest how to extract method

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 methods(* BindingSource are bindingsources, context is data context, cache* -are some List for cache operations):

```
 private void AddUpdateRowDocuments()
        {
            try
            {
                tRANSMITDOCDOCUMENTSRELATIONSBindingSource.EndEdit();
                var t = tRANSMITDOCDOCUMENTSRELATIONSBindingSource.Current as WcfDataServiceReference.TRANSMIT_DOC_DOCUMENTS_RELATIONS;
                if (t.TRANSMIT_DOC_ID == 0)
                {
                    if (!cachetddrList.Contains(t))
                    {
                        cachetddrList.Add(t);
                    }
                    return;
                }
                context.UpdateObject(t);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.ErrorException(string.Empty, ex);
            }
        }
private void AddUpdateRowOrganizations()
    {
        try
        {
            tRANSMITDOCORGANIZATIONRELATIONSBindingSource.EndEdit();
            var t = tRANSMITDOCORGANIZATIONRELATIONSBindingSource.Current as WcfDataServiceReference.TRANSMIT_DOC_ORGANIZATION_RELATIONS;
            if (t.TRANSMIT_DOC_ID == 0)
            {
                if (!cachetdorList.Contains(t))
                {
                    cachetdorList.Add(t);
                }
                return;
            }
            context.UpdateObject(t);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.ErrorException(string.Empty, ex);
        }
    }
private void AddUpdateRowPartators()
        {
            try
            {
                tRANSMITDOCPARTATORRELATIONSBindingSource.EndEdit();
                var t = tRANSMITDOCPARTATORRELATIONSBindingSource.Current as WcfDataServiceReference.TRANSMIT_DOC_PARTATOR_RELATIONS;
                if (t.TRANSMIT_DOC_ID == 0)
                {
                    if (!cachetdprList.Contains(t))
                    {
                        cachetdprList.Add(t);
                    }
                    return;
                }
                context.UpdateObject(t);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.ErrorException(string.Empty, ex);
            }
        }
```

Any thoughts on how to improve them? My inner sense says that they can be turned into one generic method, but i have little experience with generics, so cant say if i am right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along the lines of this. Generics aren't that difficult. Just replace every occurance of 'some desired type' with the generic identifier.

```
private void AddUpdateRow<T>(BindingSource bindingSource, List<T> cachedList)
    where T : ITransmitDocId
{
    try
    {
        bindingSource.EndEdit();
        T t = bindingSource.Current as T;
        if (t.TRANSMIT_DOC_ID == 0)
        {
            if (!cachedList.Contains(t))
            {
                cachedList.Add(t);
            }
            return;
        }
        context.UpdateObject(t);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.ErrorException(string.Empty, ex);
    }
}
```

The where constraint in the function definition should indicate a common interface/class in which `TRANSMIT_DOC_ID` is defined.

Comment: problem with t.TRANSMIT_DOC_ID: 'T' does not contain a definition for 'TRANSMIT_DOC_ID' and no extension method 'TRANSMIT_DOC_ID' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @nihi_l_ist: How are you calling this method? Does the error occur in the generic function or on the caller? Be sure to replace `T` with your desired type when calling the function. E.g. `AddUpdateRow<CourtWcfDataServiceReference.TRANSMIT_DOC_ORGANIZATION_RELATIONS>( bindingSource, cachedList )`.

Comment: It appears in generic method(code does't even compile)..Think T must implement some interface that should be common for all that classes(like TRANSMIT_DOC_ORGANIZATION_RELATIONS and ets..)

Comment: Ok...thank you anyway .. I'll move that t.TRANSMIT_DOC_ID to method's parameters and that all..Code will become a bit wired, but it WILL wwork :) thanks for the answer.

Comment: @nihi_l_ist: oh I see the problem now! you can add a where clause to the function ... to indicate T is at least an interface you define which defines TRANSMIT_DOC_ID. WIll update the answer.

Comment: ..i know :) but none of the input classes can implement common interface..Or i can create their partial versions and implement interface, but thats too much work for such piece of code. My point is reached here: I wanted to see how generic version would look like and youve shown me that.